What do wal_sync_method options mean?
I was reading this doc about wal_sync_method:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-WAL-SYNC-METHOD And also this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-reliability.html
wal_sync_method has 5 different options. And I have several questions about them.
Q1: Do I understand it correctly that open_datasync, fdatasync, fsync and opensync do not guarantee that data is written to non-volatile storage unless we use hdparm -W 0 to explicitly disable write-behind cache for the SSD?
Q2: Alternatively to using those 4 methods described above, we can just call fsync_writethrough and it will have the same effect, except we didn't set hdparm -W 0 at OS level, meaning that applications other than Postgres can still make use of the write-behind cache on the SSD, while postgres does not use it? Is that right?
Q3: Are there SSD's out there that use write-behind cache, but you can't disable it? Meaning that you have to ask your cloud provider about specifics of the SSD's that are used?
Q4: On this page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-reliability.html
It says that in linux we have to disable write-behind cache via hdparm -W 0 (or other similar options), but on macOS and Windows we need to use fsync_writethrough, does that mean that fsync_writethrough is not supported on linux, while it is suported on macOS and Windows?
Q5: The difference between 2 groups(sets) of parameters 1) {fdatasync, fsync, fsync_writethrough} and 2) {open_datasync, open_sync}, seems to be that the 1st group is called at each transaction commit (which can write multiple files). But when is the second group called? At every file write?
Q6: from what I understand fdatafync and open_datasync don't flush metadata to disk. Is it bad when it's not flushed? Or does postgres not use it anyways? I heard that this metadata might contain file permissions. If we flush only data but not metadata does that mean that users other than postgres now have access to this file which is a security issue?
Thanks in advance!

I won't answer, because you are asking questions about hardware that I cannot answer. But in general, you can never run a database on a disk that doesn't guarantee that after fsync returns, all the data are persisted, even if there is a power outage. So you need devices that either persist in that case or that have a battery-backed cache that degrades to flushing to the hardware if the battery is flat. Fiddling around with parameters to make it possible to run a database on inadequate storage is a bad idea.
